# Vertical alignment in lists when using multline

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, lists, typography, mathtools

I have encountered some troubles using `multline` in lists. The expression inside the environment is too low. This happens to expressions inside `flalign` also:

[image]

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
%\usepackage{showframe}
%\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
%
\usepackage{newtxmath}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\usepackage{enumitem}


%%%%%
%Definition of a new list type
\newcounter{qcounter}
\newenvironment{questions}{
    \begin{list}{ 
            \bfseries\upshape\arabic{qcounter}.
        }{
            \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{%
                \textbf{\refstepcounter{qcounter}\arabic{qcounter}##1.}}%
            \usecounter{qcounter}
            \setlength{\labelwidth}{0.5em}
            \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep+0.5em}
            \setlength{\itemsep}{2pt}
            \setlength{\listparindent}{1em}
            \setlength{\parsep}{1pt}
            \setlength{\topsep}{6pt}
        } 
    }{    
    \end{list}
}

%Command to correctly align environments in the list
\newcommand{\AL}{%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\multlinegap}{0pt}%
    ~\vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\item[]\AL
\begin{multline*}
f(x_1,\,x_2,\,x_3)=(\overline{x}_1\,\overline{x}_2\,\overline{x}_3\sim x_1x_2\overline{x}_3)\sim\\
\sim(x_1\overline{x}_2x_3\sim\overline{x}_1x_2x_3);
\end{multline*}


\item[]\AL
\begin{flalign*}
&\bigoplus\limits_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}x_ix_j\oplus\bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_i\,,\quad n\geqslant 2.&
\end{flalign*}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

I am searching for some global solution, not like putting `~\hspace*{-3.5pt}` every time.

**UPDATE.** Some strange space appears when using `multlined`:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
%\usepackage{showframe}
%\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
%
\usepackage{newtxmath}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\usepackage{enumitem}


%%%%%
%Definition of a new list type
\newcounter{qcounter}
\newenvironment{questions}{
    \begin{list}{ 
            \bfseries\upshape\arabic{qcounter}.
        }{
            \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{%
                \textbf{\refstepcounter{qcounter}\arabic{qcounter}##1.}}%
            \usecounter{qcounter}
            \setlength{\labelwidth}{0.5em}
            \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep+0.5em}
            \setlength{\itemsep}{2pt}
            \setlength{\listparindent}{1em}
            \setlength{\parsep}{1pt}
            \setlength{\topsep}{6pt}
        } 
    }{    
    \end{list}
}

%Command to correctly align environments in the list
\newcommand{\AL}{%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\multlinegap}{0pt}%
}


\begin{document}

    \begin{questions}

        \item[]\AL
        $\begin{multlined}[t]
        f(x_1,\,x_2,\,x_3)=(\overline{x}_1\,\overline{x}_2\,\overline{x}_3\sim x_1x_2\overline{x}_3)\sim\\
        \sim(x_1\overline{x}_2x_3\sim\overline{x}_1x_2x_3);
        \end{multlined}$


        \item[]\AL
        $\begin{aligned}[t]
        f(x_1,\,x_2,\,x_3)=(\overline{x}_1\,\overline{x}_2\,\overline{x}_3\sim x_1x_2\overline{x}_3)\sim\sim(x_1\overline{x}_2x_3\sim\overline{x}_1x_2x_3);
        \end{aligned}$

    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @campa Unfortunately, I need to use alignment stuff, I just gave bad examples in the MWE

Comment: My experiments have shown that *that* is where the baseline is for \AL\begin{multiline}.  It has nothing to do with \item or the question environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are variations of the standard `align` & Co. which can be used as building blocks in math mode, namely `aligned` & Co. As far as I understand, you do not need `flalign*` here at all but can use simply

```
\item $\begin{aligned}[t] a &= b \\ &= c \end{aligned}$
```

The optional argument `[t]` tells to align the baseline of the first line of `aligned` with the external baseline. There is an equivalent `multlined` too (defined by `mathtools`, while `aligned` comes with `amsmath`).

(BTW, you need to put every time `\item[]` because of an unfortunate definition of the `questions` environment. I can't think this is on porpose...)

Comment: It works, thank you. `item` is defined so I can do something like `\item[${}^{\ast}$]` to mark the difficult tasks.

Comment: There's also `multlined`, which can be handy for this case.

Comment: @egreg Something strange is going on when I use `multlined`: there appears am additional space before the formula. I have updated the question.

Comment: @MichaelFreimann `aligned` has been updated not to add a thin space, but `multlined` hasn't (it is only in `mathtools`), so you still need `\!\begin{multlined}`.

Comment: @egreg great, thx, it works now. Is it going to be updated? Or can I redefine the environment to automatically add `\!`?

Comment: @MichaelFreimann One should ask the maintainer.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a solution, but rather shows the top and bottom of the box produced, plus the desired baseline.  Unfortunately, it appears impossible to reconstruct the desired baseline from the resulting box.

[image: dimensions]