# "aligned" environment gives too much horizontal space

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, mathtools

I am using the `aligned` environment to typeset some mathematical equations. Background was discussed here: [Vertical alignment in lists when using multline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359441/vertical-alignment-in-lists-when-using-multline). The idea is to typeset equations on the same line with text.

Now, I want to align equations by more than one position. `aligned` gives me too much space around `=`:

[image]

As you can see, there is too much space between `AA` and `=`.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$\begin{aligned}
&AA &&= a\\
&B  &&= b
\end{aligned}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: `@TeXnician because then it alignes the `b` symbol two the right border. Substitute `a` with `aaa` and you will see.

Comment: The `aligned` and `alignedat` environments are provided by `amsmath`; `mathtools` also loads it but it's independent from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `alignedat` if you do not want space between each equation

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$\begin{alignedat}{2}
&AA &&= a\\
&B &&=b
\end{alignedat}$

\end{document}
```

the form with `aligned` is modelled on setting

> a=1     b=2

with some space between each equation, so you have the right hand side of two equations, with space between.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of this environment. Guess I should read the `mathtools` documentation.

Comment: `alignedat` is described in the `amsmath` documentation, not `mathtools`.  (`mathtools` just loads `amsmath` then adds to it.)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is using the `array` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{l@{{}={}}l}
AA & a\\
B  & b
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

with the required result:

> [image]